# PPTP + LAN = Maybe?

Tags: windows, networking, cisco, cisco-vpn

This has been someone answered in another question but the question was never answered.

I've successfully set up a PPTP server at my work, and while I understand the whole point of PPTP is point-to-point, is there any configurations I could make to allow the VPN clients access to resources on the LAN they are not-really VPNing into?

PPTP server is handing out 10.1.10.200-204, can't go over 5 hosts due to RV042 limitations, and the IP addresses are handed out on the LAN at 10.1.10.1/24

It's the Microsoft VPN Client connecting to a 
RV042 VPN/Router.

The VPN subnet and the windows LAN are on the same private /24.

Comment: What do you mean by "allow the VPN clients access to resources on the LAN they are not-really VPNing into"? It looks like you're missing a correct routing setup on the client. The gateway should be router's LAN IP address.

Comment: When you VPN in with PPTP on Windows, 255.255.255.255 is the default subnet mask. It can't reach other devices on the LAN I'm VPNing into. Like if I have a web server on 10.1.10.13 and I VPN in, and I get the IP of 10.1.10.201 on the VPN interface, I can't then browse to 10.1.10.13 on the VPN'd in client.

Answer (score 0):

Add a route to your LAN on the PPTP client machines:

```
route ADD 10.1.10.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.1.10.1
```

(change *10.1.10.1* if your router's IP is different)

You don't need a reverse-side route on LAN machines, because IIRC Cisco RV042/RV082 acts as an ARP proxy on PPTP interfaces.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Tried pinging and tried SHHing into one of our servers.

Comment: A traceroute reveals it makes it to the router, but not back down

Comment: Here's the routing table http://pastebin.com/BXG1EjKf
Note the VPN router is 10.1.10.2, where the modem/router is 10.1.10.1

Comment: The output of "ipconfig /all" for the PPTP interface could be helpful too.